# Warning in MVC partial view, when <li> is not directly in <ul>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

In layout page i have `ul` with a few `li` tags inside, but i am inside also rendering partial view, in which i have `li` tags, but of course not in `ul` tag, when i run it everything renders fine, but visual studio 2012 express for web shows warning on that partial, but without any description. Any ideas or workarounds how to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Partials should be complete and reuseable. So really, it should contain the parent 'ul' element. You could always have nested lists? Other that than, I can't think of a way to stop Visual Studio showing an error.

Comment: well then, i will redesign it somehow, i thought there were some way how to trick it, but as u said i will stick to partial's reusabillity, thx

Comment: Post the relevant partial view code.  Sometimes it depends on how you are defining the html elements-- we've had projects where this occurs-- the main element would have a table and a collection property would have the <tr> and <td> elements.  I don't believe we had any issues with those showing warnings.  On the other hand, this could also be a setting within Visual Studio-- you can set several severity levels for different html inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

For the <li> tags in the partial view you could use @: or <text></text> tags if using the Razor engine.

An example:

```
@foreach(var item in items) {

   @:<li>@item</li>
```

}

or using text tags:

```
@foreach(var item in items) {

   <text><li>@item</li></text>
```

}

For more about these you can see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax